# Python for-loop, change variable not in next round

Tags: python

Hi guys im new to python. I have a question concerning a double-for loop:

```
for i in range (rounds):
    for n, data in G.nodes ().items ():
        if data ["example"] == "x":

            for neighbor in nx.all_neighbors (G, n):
                if -------------             

    for n, data in G.nodes ().items ():
        if data ["test"] == "I" and random.random () < somevalue
            data ["test"] = "R"

        if data ["test"] == "NI":
            DO Something
```

This loop at the end is changing some status in data["test"] -- Do Something. My Question: How can i setup that the status/variable is changing after 2 ROUNDS  and not next round?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: Please remove parts of code that are unrelated to your problem. They distract.

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. What is a "round"? What exactly is the behavior you want? Most of the stuff in your example seems superfluous and doesn't aid in understanding your intent. Can you make a simple, basic example?

Comment: Hi. thank you guys for your awnser. Sorry for my unclear question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what problem you're trying to solve, but if you want to skip the first item in `G.nodes()`, then there are a couple of ways you can do it. In Python 2, you could change the `for` loop to:

```
for n, data in G.nodes().items()[1:]:
```

The `[1:]` at the end causes the loop to iterate over all the elements of the list *except* the first one. This notation is called a *slice* and you can find more information at [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/893).

In Python 3, since `items()` returns an iterable, you can't use slice notation and one way to do it would be to use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import itertools

for n, data in itertools.islice(G.nodes().items(), 1, None):
```